# Export List in Parallel via ClusterExport in R

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I have a list of objects of considerate size that that i need to export to a PSOCKcluster in R.

I'm doing this in the following way:

```
cl <- makePSOCKcluster(3, methods = TRUE)

listOfMatrices <- c(bigMatrix1, bigMatrix2, bigMatrix3)

for(i in 1:3){
   bigMatrix <- listOfMatrices[i]
   clusterExport(cl[i], "bigMatrix", envir = environment())
}
```

However this approach is sequential as export n+1 needs for export n to finish first.

Is there a more efficient way to do this in parallel?

Comment: Not sure I totally understood what you wanted, but if the problem is using parallelism on big matrices, using the package bigmemory could solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with the `clusterApply` function:

```
library(parallel)
cl <- makePSOCKcluster(3)
listOfMatrices <- list(matrix(1,2,2), matrix(2,2,2), matrix(3,2,2))
clusterApply(cl, listOfMatrices, function(m) {bigMatrix <<- m; NULL})
```

You can verify that it worked correctly using `clusterEvalQ`:

```
clusterEvalQ(cl, bigMatrix)
```